# Setting up custom build environment

Tags: algorithm, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, custom-build

I am trying to set up my custom build environment for Sublime Text 3 for competitive Programming.

My target is as follows :

1. Build the current source file
2. Run it and read inputs from a file `input.in`
3. Write output to a file `output.out`
4. `diff expected output.out`. `expected` file contains the expected output

This is how the window setup looks like [image]

This is my json file for the build system

```
{
"cmd": ["g++ -std=c++11 ${file} -o ${file_path}/${file_base_name} && ${file_path}/${file_base_name}<${file_path}/input.in>${file_path}/output.out && diff output.out expected"],
"shell":true
}
```

So far steps 1-3 are working as expected. But for last step 4, I am not able to get the result in proper suitable format. e.g. when files match there is no output (as `diff` generates nothing in case of match) and in case of non-match, this build system is generating output in non human-readable format.

```
5a6
> f
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Can anyone suggest a better way to output the result or is there a way to use linux's notification utility